# Create json from array and send it in POST request body

Tags: jmeter

Consider a variable in jMeter which contains `["beep1","beep2","beep3"]`

I would like to create a JSON for a POST request which looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": {            
        "bar": {
            "baz": [
            {
                "value": "beep1"
            },
            {
                "value": "beep2"
            },
            {
                "value": "beep3"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you always have 3 arguments (so your goal is to substitute 3 values), or do you want to generate the entire JSON content, based on number of variables you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using any of [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), the relevant code would be something like:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder {
    foo {
        bar
                {
                    baz(Eval.me(vars.get('myVar')).collect { beep ->
                        [
                                value: beep

                        ]
                    })
                }
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Generate JSON out of String]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy: JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)